# Error: Initializing Argument 1 of

Tags: c++, arrays, function, function-parameter

I've looked around and seen quite a few of these, but none of them provided the solution for my problem. I'm getting this compilation error with the following code:

> **THE ERROR:**

### [image]

**THE CODE:**

```
const int TOP_WORDS = 25;

...

void topWords(Hash t, string word, string topA[]); 

int main()
{
    ...
    Hash table1;
    string word = "example";

    string topWordsArr[TOP_WORDS];

    table1.addItem(word);
    topWords(table1, word, topWordsArr);

    ...
}

...

void topWords(Hash t, string word, string topA[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int tempCount = t.itemCount(word);
    int tempCount2 = t.itemCount(topA[i]);

    while (tempCount > tempCount2 && i < TOP_WORDS) {
        i++;
        tempCount2 = t.itemCount(topA[i]);
    }

    if (i > 0)
```

All the other posts I've seen about this error involved an incorrect syntax with declaring/passing the string array parameter, but I've double and triple checked it all and I'm certain it's correct; though I've been wrong before..

Comment: You're getting *what* compilation error? You only posted half of one.

Comment: I can't believe this. The compiler clearly states argument 1, and all you've shown about argument 1 is `param1`. It's not possible at all to figure out what's wrong with something that isn't shown.

Comment: Apologies I accidentally hit enter which posted it before I was finished writing it. Fixing it now.

Comment: Still nowhere near the complete error message. There is another line or two containing the specifics, like a conversion error or something.

Comment: @molbdnilo the error is the entirety of what the compiler spits out at me. The only thing I didn't put is "p5.cpp:29:6: error:" which I will add for completeness. But that is all of it.

Comment: @user3776749 There will be at least some more lines of output (usually with `Note: ....`). Include them. Or, you know, maybe post a [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: What type is `Hash`?

Comment: It's like I said, that's the whole message, start to finish. Hash is a hash table type I've defined. I think the answer sehe posted might be the ticket. I will report back soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using my crystal ball:

- you're passing the `Hash` by value
- this requires the copy constructor,
- you don't have one (or it's botched, private or explicit)

So, take the `Hash` by reference

```
void topWords(Hash const& t, std::string const& word, std::string* topA);
```

Also,

- `string[]` is not a type in C++
- don't use `using namespace std;`
- don't use raw arrays; use `std::vector<std::string>` (or `std::array<std::string, N>`)

Comment: upon fixing this, the OP will *likely* encounter a "cannot call non-const member `Hash::itemCount()` from const object `t`" message (or close to that, anyway). It may be `const` already, but given the posted code I somewhat suspect it isn't. (and +1)

Comment: Ah don't be pessimist :) I use my crystal ball for "good" (well, ... I hope)

Comment: ... heh, you have your crystal ball (horked copy-ctor), I have mine =P

Comment: I think this might be it. Will report back soon.

Sadly "using namespace std;" is required for this (school) class, and we aren't allowed to use std::vector for some reason. that part is gettin really frustrating because a lot of the answers to questions I post here involve using std::vector.

Comment: @user3776749 There's nothing inherently wrong with `using namespace std` except you are bringing in a lot of names that may conflict with names in your code; as long as you are aware of what is happening, do what is most convenient for your given situation.  Same with your use of raw, fixed-size arrays, feel free to use them but understand their limitations and caveats with respect to dynamic containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: @sehe Answers containing sentence that start with "don't use" are generally improved by elaborating on *why* and on what the risks of using those things are (and when it may be acceptable to use them). Otherwise you end up with things like the "goto is considered harmful" culture. A good quality of a programmer is to know *why* they aren't using the things they're told not to use.

Comment: @JasonC LUCKILY they are on SO: [Why is `using namespace std` considered a bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The OP already knows that vector is probably a good match here (I think the `topA` is likely an output parameter... Should really be a vector return value then). By the way "goto considered harmful" is a prototypical example of a \**wel-argued** piece. I'd be happy to be ranked in that culture (but I'm probably much too lazy)

Comment: @sehe "Goto considered harmful" was not the intended title of that paper, and regret was later expressed for good reason, well-stated argument aside. As for the "don't use", you are right, the info is easily searchable, but I hypothesize that the typical audience here (not necessarily speaking of the OP) does not do much in the way of searching!

Comment: @JasonC I wager that's not really my problem. I can only prod and suggest. Curiosity will have to spark on the other side :) (By spelling things out over and over we just remove the incentive to start using search)

Comment: @ sehe, that's what I meant (about the frustrating thing), and I do actually do a lot of reading on various structures, libraries, and classes in my own time, even if I don't use them in class.

I spent a month this summer digging into COMs. It's way beyond most of the stuff in my course work, and even though I'm sure I don't grasp a lot of the subtleties it was definitely a profitable venture.

I greatly appreciate all the help I get on here, and look forward to giving back once I'm more experienced.

Comment: Also the answer was correct. I suppressed copying in my hashtable class for the obvious reasons. Passing the object by references fixed the problem.

Comment: @sehe I've posted a follow-up question since you seemed to have ignored my comment. [Is string\[\] not a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117169/is-string-not-a-type/27117272)

Comment: @remyabel I missed that. I should have probably said "string[]" is not - per se - a complete type. Of course, a static object of type `string[]` can exist and then will get a complete type later on. But, `string[]` as in VLA area C99 thing, not in c++ at all (although g++ might accept it as a GNU extension)

Comment: @sehe You being a high rep user I thought you were being excessively pedantic about some obscure language feature I was unaware of. Of course it was as simple as I thought it was. Thanks.